# Получить имя установленного антивируса

Tags: c++, windows, wmi

Как получить имя установленного антивируса? Пока на ум приходит лишь два варианта, хотя у них есть свои "но":

1. Парсить `uninstall` ветку реестра? Не вариант - придётся хранить данные всех `АВ` в программе.
2. Получать информацию об установленном `АВ` посредством взаимодействия с `WMI`? Я, погуглив, нашёл пример с подключением к `ROOT\SecurityCenter`, но проблема в том что он не работает в серверных ОС.

Есть ли какой-нибудь универсальный вариант получения имени установленного антивируса, работающий на всех ОС или костыль конкретно под серверные?

Comment: А чем,  по-вашему, антивирус отличается от любой другой программы в смысле своей "установленности"?

Comment: @СНижнегоТагила, антивирусы и фаерволлы умеют особым образом регистрироваться в ОС.

Comment: Хорошо бы кто-нибудь ответ перевел: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459350/how-to-detect-if-a-virusscanner-and-or-firewall-is-installed-and-a-few-other-s

Comment: А толку? Для серверных OS нормального решения нету.

Comment: @Nofate Ответ хорош, но сейчас проверил, а не работает (может, только здесь) - установлен Symantec SEP 12.1RU5, ОС семерка х64, в AntivirusProduct пустота. При этом на другом ПК стоит RU1, и запись есть (или от RU1 только запись WMI). Интере-е-есно.

Comment: Вот нашел на плюсах (!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396757/how-to-detect-antivirus-installed-on-windows-2003-server-and-2008-server-2003-se тут код есть, интересно, пойдет?

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы один из задокументированных способов является WMI. Однако не забывайте, то чтобы использовать этот механизм нужны будут права администратора. На вашем месте я бы пожалуй просто сделал detect по названию процесса.